# How to set vibrate and sound on Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a class that implements an alarm. The receiver class is a broadcast receiver and I would like it to vibrate and play the default alarm sound when the alarm goes off. But it won't let me use getSystemService in the broadcast receiver class.

Im guessing this is because it's not an activity and can't use it but how do I get around this? Should I change my receiving class to an activity class or alert dialog activity? What do you all suggest?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it. I do it in my BroadcastReceiver.

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Do you have an error message? Or source code?

Please know that a broadcastreceiver only lasts 10 seconds at maximum.

Answer (score 2):

The getSystemService method is part of the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) class. In your Broadcast receiver you'll be passed a `Context` instance with the Broadcast Intent. The context will either be an Activity Context or an Application Context, depending on how your Broadcast receiver was registered.

You should be able to use this `Context` instance to call `getSystemService` like so:

```
public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: @twaddington You solved my problem too.I wasn't using `context.getSystemService()` but only `getSystemService()` so it was showing error.